# Directing files in different folders through couple programs with .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file

Basically, I'm trying to batch-compress `.png` images which are residing in various folders. For that, I use pngquant and pngout. Every image should go through these apps this way:

```
pngquant.exe --force --speed 1 --verbose image.png -o step1.png
pngout.exe step1.png step2.png
```

I want all images compressed at once. To gather a list of all images in folders, I search with `*.png` query in root folder. The aim is to just throw all images to batch file and wait for the result.

I looked around a bit and come up with this

```
for %%i in (*.png) do (
"...\pngquant.exe" --force --speed 1 --verbose "%%~ni.png" -o "%%~ni2.png"
"...\pngout.exe" "%%~ni2.png" "%%~ni3.png" )
```

So I'm dragging the images onto the .bat file, but only the images from the first folder would go through, the batch file ignores images from the subsequent folders. How can I fix that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir *.png /s /b') do (
"pngquant.exe" --force --speed 1 --verbose "%%i" -o "%%~di%%~pi%%~ni2.png"
"pngout.exe" "%%~di%%~pi%%~ni2.png" "%%~di%%~pi%%~ni3.png" )
```

try this. but note that PNGs will be created in the same folders. don't know however if it was your intent.

Comment: +1 You can also use terms like `"%%~dpni2%%~xi"` and `"%%~dpni3%%~xi"` to replace `"%%~di%%~pi%%~ni2.png"` etc

Answer (score 0):

Dropping files on the batch file is the same as providing them as arguments on the command line. Your script ignores its arguments and processes just its working directory.

Replace the `for` argument `(*.png)` with `(%*)`, which contains the list of all arguments.
Also, instead of `%%~ni`, which returns just the name of the file, you'll need to say `%%~dpni`, to include the drive and path, if the files are not in the same folder as the script.